# How to override properly invoke method on SignalR

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I hope you are safe and doing well;

I've been working with SignalR and trying to create a better approach to handle when it is disconnected.

So, I create this piece of code to override the invoke and then add the request on an array (if disconnected) to execute after;;

```
 const tobeExecuted = [];

 myHub.start().then(() => {
    while (tobeExecuted.length > 0) {
      const delayed = tobeExecuted.pop()
      delayed()
    }
  })

 myHub.invoke = (function (_super) {
    if (appHub.connectionState === 'Connecting') {
      return function () {
        tobeExecuted.push(() => {
          _super.apply(this, arguments)
        })
      }
    }

    return function () {
      return _super.apply(this, arguments)
    }
  }(myHub.invoke))
```

It works, however when I tried to use .then like

```
 myHub.invoke("whenever").then(a => console.log(a))
```

.then is not defined. I know it is a Promisse, but don't know how to return properly

Can someone help?

Comment: What client package are you using?

Comment: vanilla javascript

Comment: I mean SignalR package.

Comment: It is our React app using  "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4"

Comment: You can switch to the new package `@microsoft/signalr` that provides you the automatic reconnect function.

Comment: aspnet/signalr also have reconnected function, but I need to save the commands when it is disconnected and then call them when I got a connection. For this, I save it into an array, however when I need use ".then" I can't